# how to send input text value or data one view to another view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-routing

could you please tell me how to send data from one view to another view .Actually I have one input field and button on my main screen .I want to send data of input text from one screen to another screen on button click .I want to send text of input field from one view to another view .I am able to move one screen to another on button click but I am not able to send input text on another screen

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/pz9NBhtq4fX0m6N4wDqB?p=preview

```
 events: {
         'click #click':'moveTonext'
        },

       moveTonext: function(){
          new Router().navigate('secondView', { trigger: true });
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that you need to instantiate your `SecondView` from the `.moveToNext()` function, and provide the necessary parameters:

```
// app.js
moveTonext: function(){
    new SecondView({ 
        model: new Backbone.Model({
            value: this.$("input").val()
        })
    });
},
```

You also need to update your second view to provide the model's attributes to the template:

```
// second.js
render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
},
```

And the template itself:

```
// second.html
<h1>Value from previous page: <%- value %></h1>
```

Here's an updated [Plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/kcbNSCMgMG75njPKJlIu?p=preview).

#### Edit

The same can be achieved using parameterized routes:

```
// router.js
routes: {
    'secondView(/:msg)': 'secondView'
},

secondView: function(msg) {
  new SecondView({ model: new Backbone.Model({ value: msg || '' }) });
}

// app.js
moveTonext: function() {
    new Router().navigate(
        'secondView/' + this.$('input').val(),
        { trigger: true }
    );
},
```

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ctMbqBBqcYIXKGpDzY9C?p=preview) for this.

Comment: THANKS FOR ANSWER..!! CAN we pass value of input field on url ? and fetch the value from url

Comment: mean on router can we define like this ":inputvalue" :"somefunction" and get value on second page

Comment: Yes, you can. You can read about routing capabilities here: http://backbonejs.org/#Router

Comment: yes thanks can you please make one addition plunker how i will achieve this

Comment: could you please make one plunker using router concept I will be thankful to you

Comment: @Shruti, if that answer solves your problem, please, consider upvoting it or marking as answer. Or both